# SIGCHLD on SIGKILL

Tags: c, linux, bash, fork, zombie-process

**Program fork_wait.c :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(){
    pid_t a = fork();
    if (a != 0) {
        int status;
        printf("I am your father. (...) You know it to be true !");
        wait(&status);
    }
    else {
        printf("NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!! NOOOOOOO!!");
        sleep(2000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Bash :**

```
$ cc fork_wait.c -o fork_wait && ./fork_wait
I am your father. (...) You know it to be true !
NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!! NOOOOOOO!!
```

**Bash while execution :**

```
$ pgrep fork_wait
37818
37819

$ kill -9 $(pgrep fork_wait | tail -1)
$ pgrep fork_wait
(nothing)
```

Who sends the SIGCHLD signal when the process is killed with SIGTERM ? Why is there no zombie process if I kill the son ?

Comment: A child process whose parent is killed is not a "zombie", it is an "orphan" that is being adopted by `init`.

Comment: You can't catch SIGKILL signals.  Your code does not set any signal handlers.  The parent waited for the child but exited.  Your second (third) `pgrep` doesn't find it because it's gone.  You should print information about dead children in a loop: `int corpse; int status; while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0) print("Child PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't kill the parent but the child

Comment: But the parent waits for the child, cleaning up what might otherwise have been a zombie process when it does so.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't try to catch the SIGKILL signal but to understand what happens there, ie who sends SIGCHLD to the father when you SIGKILL a son. Why is the father awoken

Comment: The OS is sending this signal.

Comment: Unless your parent process arranges to handle SIGCHLD, the signal is not sent to the parent.  The kernel sends the signal when it is sent.

Comment: Is there an interrupt or so that does that immediately after the SIGKILL, or is it some recurring checks by the kernel ?

Comment: When you kill the process, the OS is terminating it and is doing all the cleanup stuff, including sending the necessary signals.

Comment: Processes are not gendered.  It is "parent" and "child", not "father" and "son".

Comment: There *is* a zombie process when you kill the child, but it is a zombie for a very short time.  It is only a zombie between the time it is terminated and the time its parent `wait`s for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an adaptation of your first program.  It uses the default SIGCHLD signal handling, which means that the signals are not delivered (by the kernel) to the parent process when a child dies (`forkwait29.c`):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t a = fork();
    if (a != 0)
    {
        printf("%5d: I am your father. (...) You know it to be true!\n", getpid());
        int corpse;
        int status;
        while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
            printf("PID %5d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%5d: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!! NOOOOOOO!!\n", getpid());
        sleep(2000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

An example run yields:

```
$ forkwait29
64001: I am your father. (...) You know it to be true!
64002: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!! NOOOOOOO!!
PID 64002 exited with status 0x0009
$
```

You could analyze the status returned (using `WIFSIGNALED`, `WIFTERMSIG`, `WIFEXITED`, `WEXITSTATUS`, `WCOREDUMP`, etc) and it would show that the child died because it received signal 9, SIGKILL.  As pointed out in the comments, your parent collected the dead child process (preventing it from becoming a (long-lasting) zombie) and exited.

You could add some signal handling like this (`forkwait73.c`):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static volatile sig_atomic_t sig_caught = 0;

static void sig_handler(int signum)
{
    sig_caught = signum;
}

int main(void)
{
    pid_t a = fork();
    if (a != 0)
    {
        printf("%5d: I am your father. (...) You know it to be true!\n", getpid());
        struct sigaction sa = { 0 };
        sa.sa_handler = sig_handler;
        sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
        if (sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask) != 0)
            return 1;
        sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL);
        int corpse;
        int status;
        while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        {
            printf("PID %5d exited with status 0x%.4X (caught = %d)\n",
                   corpse, status, sig_caught);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%5d: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!! NOOOOOOO!!\n", getpid());
        sleep(2000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

One sample run produced:

```
$ forkwait73
63964: I am your father. (...) You know it to be true!
63965: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!! NOOOOOOO!!
PID 63965 exited with status 0x000F (caught = 20)
$
```

When I omitted the `SA_RESTART` flag on macOS Moneterey 12.2.1, I got a result like:

```
$ forkwait73
63929: I am your father. (...) You know it to be true!
63930: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!! NOOOOOOO!!
$
```

Without the SA_RESTART, the parent process did not report the death of its child because the `wait()` failed with `errno == EINTR`.  Instead of setting SA_RESTART, the loop could be revised to:

```c
        while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0 || errno == EINTR)
        {
            printf("PID %5d exited with status 0x%.4X (caught = %d)\n",
                   corpse, status, sig_caught);
            errno = 0;
        }
```

If you want to see a zombie process, you have to arrange for the parent not to `wait()` for the child for a while.  You could have it sleep too, and when the `sleep()` call finishes, it could continue with the `wait()` loop.  You might arrange for it to handle another signal too so you can signal it to wake up and spot that it's child has died.

Comment: Thanks for your answer that allows me to notice the SIGCHLD signal (17 on my system). why is the volatile keyword needed ? The handler behaves like an external modification ?

Comment: The C standard severely limits what you can do in a [signal handler](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.14.1.1p5); POSIX is a lot more [lenient](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04).  One of the things the C standard says is that you can write to a variable of type `volatile sig_atomic_t`, so that's what this code does.